# How to extract to a particular file format using WINRAR

Tags: winrar, winzip

Suppose I have a WinRAR file, and I want to extract to a csv file. When I select the option 'Extract to here' it just extracts the file without any extension. Is there a way I can specify that I want the extracted file to be of csv format?

Comment: When you double-click on it, does it open in Excel?

Comment: It sounds like the file contained in the archive does not have a file extension.

Comment: Eh...? The whole point of compression programs such as WinZip, WinRAR, 7-Zip etc. is that they create a container with your compressed files inside. When you use the `Extract to here` Windows Explorer menu option then you are telling the compression software to extract the files to the directory suggested by the software (mostly the same folder as where the original compressed file is located)... I'm fairly sure you can't specify a type of file to extract an archive folder to, because it's not a specific file type... it could be many different file types...

Comment: So if I want to convert to csv, I have to first extract to file, then open in excel and save as csv? What if the file is too big to open?

Comment: Then use a different program that can open bigger files.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't specify the type of output file, WINRAR does not do any conversion, it will just decompress whatever file type was originally compressed. So you get to choose the location of output, but that's about it.

If it extracts a file with no extension then you need to open the file in notepad or excel or similar to see if it is a .csv, and if not, use excel or similar to save it as one.

If the file size is too big, you can try another editor such as Notepad ++ or you can split the file into smaller chunks.